# click function on overlapped items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlap

I have something like this:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
<body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').fadeToggle('fast');
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $('div').find('p').fadeOut();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Qb7/)

How to prevent back item to be clicked when clicking front item ?

Comment: Use event.stopPropagation(); to prevent back item click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) or need to return false from `click` event handler.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Qb7/5/)**

```
$('div').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('p').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

> **Description:** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: +1 Or `return false` (which will both stop propagation and prevent the default, which in this case is nothing, so...).

Answer (score 1):

To stop the event from propagating, you need to `return false` from the event handler.

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).find('p').fadeToggle('fast');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience in jQuery but this works:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

instead of

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').fadeToggle('fast');
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $('div').find('p').fadeOut();
});
```